# Can't install Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit on a dual-drive MacBook Pro 8,2

Tags: boot, macbook, ssd

Good afternoon, this is the first time I participate here as I'm new to Linux. I've been trying to solve the following problem for over a week without any sign of success so I hope there's a much more knowledgeable person here that can give me a solution.

I have an early 2011 MacBook Pro (8,2) with Mac OS X running in a SSD. Then, instead of the Optical bay, I have a HDD in where I would like to install Ubuntu to run it natively.
I've tried to do the normal installation process, with or without rEFIt, but it seems the problem resides on the communication between the device containing the Ubuntu .iso file and the laptop. It doesn't allow communication with the boot CD or USB drive. It usually says: “Loading bootlogo...” after I click on the “boot from CD, Linux Icon”.

After trying several things, I would like to know if I could install Ubuntu on the HDD as an external HDD (using a friend's Window's system) and then simply put it back into my laptop so as to become an Internal HDD again. I guess, I would have to reinstall many drivers and so on, but would this approach work?

Thanks in advance and sorry for this huge block of text

Answer (score 1):

You are using a USB drive that has a mounted Ubuntu 12.04 image on it, correct?

When you boot into the Ubuntu installer, the purple console based one, you will have an option to set some boot parameters. After selecting install language, you're greeted with a menu to try a live Ubuntu version, install, (and other stuff). If you look at the bottom, you will see that you can press F6 to turn on or off a few boot options.

EDIT: Here's a screen shot: http://img827.imageshack.us/img827/3509/dgfdgrunningoraclevmvir.png

When I installed 12.04 on my Macbook Pro 5,2, I realized that I had to select the "nomodeset" option. After this, I could install 12.04.  This webpage also says that the "noapic" and "nolapic" flags need to be on. I would suggest trying the combinations of these boot parameters (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132).